# How to convert Objective-C App Delegate to Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, appdelegate

I am working on old projects converting all classes to Swift.

How can I convert the `AppDelegate` class to Swift?

What changes must me made in the Project settings or `main.m`?

Comment: Several steps but easily doable. I have my script for this at the office, if you don't have an answer by tomorrow I'll post it.

Comment: But you need to add like an @main at the top of the swift file, and get rid of the main.m and main.h files

Comment: your main should be a main.swift

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A good starting point is to create a new Swift-Project to get the Template for the `AppDelegate`, or just copy the following code in your `AppDelegate.swift` class:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }
    
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }
    
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }
    
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }
    
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }
    
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground.
    }
}
```

In Swift the `main.m` and `AppDelegate` class have been merged by using the `@UIApplicationMain` annotation. Therefore `main.m` is not required any longer and should be deleted from your project.

It's also not required to change your Project setting, hence the `@UIApplicationMain` will do the work for you. Just be sure to set the correct Target Membership of your `AppDelegate` class if you have more build targets with different `AppDelegates`.

Comment: @seeya do you mean we can delete `main.m`?

Comment: @aircraft yes you can

Comment: What about the `SceneDelegate.swift`? The screen turns black after the white launch screen.

Comment: I'd say you don't need to put in all those other functions unless you're overriding them. The one with the Boolean return is I think the only one that is required?

Answer (score 17):

1. Create a new file in Xcode (File > New > File…) and select a Cocoa Touch Class. Call it AppDelegate, make it a subclass of UIResponder and change the language to Swift.
2. Fill the AppDelegate.swift file with:

   ```
   import UIKit

   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
       var window: UIWindow?

       func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:     NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
           // Override point for customization after application launch.

           return true
       }
   }
   ```
3. Remove your main.m and main.h files.

It's done!

Source: http://www.binpress.com/tutorial/converting-an-objective-c-app-to-swift/118

Comment: thanks for your answer,this is nice way to convert appDelegate class

Comment: @Fawad Masud My project has no `main.h`, and if I remove `main.m`, there will report a `error`.

Comment: @aircraft remove main.m as well and compile project.

Comment: @Fawad Masud You right, I do this, and now it become normal.

Answer (score 4):

In order to improve @seeya [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31309617/1979882)

**SWIFT 3**

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

}
```

Comment: @Vyacheslav should I remove `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m` ? but in the `main.m` require the `AppDelegate.h`.

Comment: @aircraft. Yiu need not main.m file more. You have to remove. uiapplicationmain word do the same as main.m

Comment: You have to remove all these files

Comment: @Vyacheslav You are right, before there will report an error, but now I clean my project and run again, there is no this issue now.

Answer (score 1):

None of previous answers worked for me, after some researches, this worked:

```
import Foundation

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
  var window: UIWindow?
  var bridge: RCTBridge!

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let jsCodeLocation: URL

    jsCodeLocation = RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(forBundleRoot: "index.ios", fallbackResource:nil)
    let rootView = RCTRootView(bundleURL: jsCodeLocation, moduleName: "REPLACE_BY_YOUR_PROJECT_NAME", initialProperties: nil, launchOptions: launchOptions)
    let rootViewController = UIViewController()
    rootViewController.view = rootView

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()



    return true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Pasting solutions from the above answers, causes Xcode to suggest updating the function declaration to mark it a `private`. In this case the function will not be called by the system, and your app will never launch.*

**Swift 5**

Use `AppDelegate.swift` as follows:

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let rootViewController = UIViewController() // replace with your view controller
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = rootViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```